# Unable to create role on Parse.com using CloudCode

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, role

I want to create Role objects in my Parse.com app using a cloud code function.
The code I have tried is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addRole",function(request,response) {
  var publicReadACL = new Parse.ACL();
  publicReadACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
  var user=Parse.User.current();
  var baserolename=request.params.organisation;
  var roleType=request.params.roleType;
  var roleName=baserolename+"_"+roleType;
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var role = new Parse.Role(roleName,publicReadACL);
  var occupants=role.getUsers();
  occupants.add(user);  
  role.save(role).then (function(role) {
      response.success(role.toJSON());
  },
  function(error) {
            response.error(error);
  });
});
```

Running this function doesn't create the role and gives a response of `{"code":105}` - no further error message. 105 seems to mean "Invalid Key Name", but I am not sure which key is invalid or why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a slightly modified version to work. Here's the Typescript version that I've just tested:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('addRole', (req: Parse.Cloud.FunctionRequest, res: Parse.Cloud.FunctionResponse) => {

    let publicReadACL = new Parse.ACL();
    publicReadACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    let user = req.user;

    let baseRoleName: string = req.params.organisation;
    let roleType: string = req.params.roleType;
    let roleName: string = `${baseRoleName}_${roleType}`;

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    let role = new Parse.Role(roleName, publicReadACL);

    let occupants = role.getUsers();
    occupants.add(user);

    role.save()
        .then((role: Parse.Role) => {
            res.success(role.toJSON())
        }, res.error);

});
```

Key differences:

- How the user is obtained. (this should not matter. I tested your version of obtaining the current user and that worked fine too)
- How the role is saved.

Here's the compiled Javascript version:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('addRole', function (req, res) {
    var publicReadACL = new Parse.ACL();
    publicReadACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    var user = req.user;
    var baseRoleName = req.params.organisation;
    var roleType = req.params.roleType;
    var roleName = baseRoleName + "_" + roleType;
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var role = new Parse.Role(roleName, publicReadACL);
    var occupants = role.getUsers();
    occupants.add(user);
    role.save()
        .then(function (role) {
        res.success(role.toJSON());
    }, res.error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was going crazy with this and it was just because I put the argument in `save`.  Honestly my worst nightmare would be having to work with Javascript all day.

Comment: Likewise here. Typescript just saves a whole class of minor errors which can be a real pain to debug later.